# Designing MongoDB collections vs relational approach

Tags: mongodb, meteor, nosql

I have difficulties in designing my MongoDB collections to fit my requirements. I only used SQL databases in my previous projects and am quite new to the NoSQL concept of MongoDB. My current learning project to get that concept is to store and retrieve statistics of games played (enhanced leaderboard example). In a relational database I would create the following tables:

```
Matches
:_id
:game_id    (reference to the type of game played)
:startedAt
:endedAt

Results
:match_id
:player_id  (reference to the users collection)
:field_id
:value
```

A match can have n players and each can have n results. Depending on the type of game, multiple result values indicated by field_id need to be entered for every player (e.g. number of points and whether the user won or not -> two fields = two rows in the results table).
As I understood that in MongoDB the concept is to store related information in one collection I tried to ignore what I did with relational DBs in the past year and created the following collection structure:

```
Matches
:_id
:game_id
:startedAt
:endedAt
:players [{
    :player_id
    :results [{
        :field_id
        :value
    }]
}]
```

However I now have difficulties to calculate the overall results for a specific player. Queries as "calculate total sum of points player A had in game B" are quite complex and I fear that the performance is very bad. Therefore I would still prefer the relational model for this case. But as I wanted to learn the concepts of a NoSQL database I still wonder, whether I just misconcepted the DB and there is a good way to structure the data in a single collection for the queries.

Any recommendations are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I am new to MongoDB, recently started learning but here is what I know so far:

NOSQL databases, such as MongoDB, are mainly used for their scalability and flexibility. For simple and small projects, I don't see a benefit.

The case you described is a classic case that SQL should be used.

If I was chosen to create that database and I HAD to use MongoDB, I would do it this way:
1) Keep the collection you created for the matches and
2) add a new collection based on the players.

The 2nd collection would be used for the leaderboards and for everything player-based. This means that there would be duplicate data but there is no other way to deal with the player searches, the ones you will need to do for the leaderboards.

Maybe it could work if only the latest matches were saved but still I see no benefit.

As I mentioned before I am in the learning process too, so I am not 100% sure.

Good luck with your project.